# Export-Csv .csv file is not properly formatted

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-csv

I have this line of code that gets me all the AD users from my Active Directory server but when I look the CSV file it generates (open with Excel) then the file is not formatted properly.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=mydomainname, dc=local" |
    Select-Object name, samaccountname |
    Export-Csv -path "\\mypcname\c$\ADusers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I expected the output to be like:

```
Column1 Column2
Jon Doe JDoe
```

And it is:

```
name,"samaccountname"
Guest,"Guest"
```

all in one column.

**Edit:**

Requested screenshot:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Normally, we do not approve of screen shots, but this is an exception. Please load the file into Excel, and then take a screen shot of Excel with this file displayed and edit the screen shot into your question here. The text that you've posted is a proper CSV file, and if your Excel is working properly, you should see two columns, headed `name` and `samaccountname`, and the respective values, one user per line, below.

Comment: i edited the question with screenshot as required @JeffZeitlin

Comment: Try doing the export without the `-Encoding UTF8`. Excel is not recognizing your file as a proper CSV, and that's the most likely reason.

Comment: it didnt work unfortunately i get the very same csv

Comment: Does import-csv work on the file?  I've seen Excel have problems with unicode format.  What format does Notepad say it is if you save as?

Comment: Highly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically

Comment: You might use another delimiter. Depending on your locale setting Excel might reserve the default ',' (comma) for something else.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin i can do it manually from excel with the comma delimiter. I was hoping if the script can do it itself.

Comment: Your CSV and PowerShell code are fine; it's Excel that has the problem with the CSV. Did you check the "Highly Relevant" link I gave you? You may need to insert the BOM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly display .csv files within Excel 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17953679/how-to-correctly-display-csv-files-within-excel-2013)

Comment: i thank everybody for  the replies. export to csv is broken either way. I exported it to json instead