# How to know the .csv field delimiter for the data copied to the clipboard by Excel

Tags: c#, excel, field, clipboard, delimiter

How to know the .csv field delimiter for the data copied to the clipboard by Excel?

Is there a way to know what is the standard field delimiter that an export should use?
Please note, that like for me (Canada-French), the double value separator is comma "," and the field delimiter seems to be semicolon ";".

So how to know what Excel will use as field delimiter to export its data to the clipboard?

Answer (score 2):

The default is tab. If you copy data from Excel and paste it into a text editor tabs separate the cells.

Comment: I would figure the question is about programmatically determining the separation character from a saved csv file, not manually copying cells from Excel.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes could be, I didn't think of that. But he said clipboard, so I'm not sure it's programmatic.

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on your excel/csv file and open with Notepad, you will see what is the type of delimiter set in your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Saved-to-disk csv files don't have any metadata storage, so you don't have a bullet-proof way of determining if a csv file is delimited by a comma, a semicolon, a pipe, the word "something", or any other character.

There is [a standard for how csv files are created](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt), but, uh, well, you know how that goes...

Microsoft [decides to do their own thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10141147/1043380), changing the character based on "Regional and Language Options". If your program is running on the same box as the Excel app that made the file, you *might* be able to programmatically determine that.

I'd say your best bet to *infer* the separation character is by looking at the first line - the headers. HOPEFULLY you don't have a comma in your header fields, and you can have a whitelist of expected separation characters. When you look at that header line, if you see a comma, you know the whole file is separated by commas, or semicolons if you see a semicolon.

This, of course, is not perfect. If you have any control over making Excel consistently printing csv's with the same separator character, that's always going to be a much better solution. Or, when importing a file, ask the user which format the file is in (comma csv vs semicolon csv, etc).

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, I think there is no way to make sure what Excel will use as field delimiter into the clipboard for the "CSV" format. Also, if there is a way, then it would depends on the version of excel on the PC (if there is only one) and also could only be by user.

My needs was to ensure a consistant way to paste from excel and decided to go with the "Text" format instead of the "CSV" format. Just to make sure everyone understand what I mean: When you "cut" or copy" in Excel, there is many formats (type) the data is put into the clipboard.

To know the available formats:

```
    IDataObject dataObj = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject();

    if (dataObj != null)
    {
        string[] formats = dataObj.GetFormats();
```

Using the "Text" format (`formats.Contains(DataFormats.Text)`) ensure the use of tab ("\t") field delimiter and carriage return + line feed ("\r\n") as line delimiter. The format is fixed and never change. It is consistent all the time.

Thanks to everyone who give answer. They are all good but I wanted to add some additional information.